# Script for compress of file and send zip with mail

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have a log folder(as.log) and I fill this log with script(basic `for` loop). If this folder size is bigger than 150kb, this folder should be compressed and its name should contain date. Finally zip file should be sent with mail automatically.

```
FILESIZE=$(stat -c%s as.log) 
if [" $FILESIZE" -gt "150000" ]; then 
zip -r "as.log-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip" as.log 
here sendmail kaanmrzl@gmail.com < as.log.zip
here truncate -s 0 as.log
fi
```

my auto filler script is

```
for i in {1..1000}
  do 
   echo "$i log kaydı" >> as.log 
done
```

Comment: unclear, what is your question? Your code looks like it should work, expect I don't know if you're using a program call `here` to run `sendmail` and `truncate`. or are those 2 lines meant as psuedo-code? Please update your Q rather than reply in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never sent an email on bash, but this should work for zipping a folder which exceeds size of 150K. Hope it helps.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

directory="/path/to/log_dir"
threshold=150
output="/path/to/log-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").zip"

dir_size=$(du -k $directory | cut -f1)
if [ "$dir_size" -gt "$threshold" ]
then
    zip -r $output $directory
fi
```